# Why is my vue development server not updating after a change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

First post so don't roast me too hard.

I am running a development server for my Vue app with `npm run serve`. The server takes several minutes to start and build. I read online that my changes should reload the server, this is not the case. I am new to Vue and npm so I am not sure what to do.

Here is what my terminal says:

```
npm run serve

> myapp@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve --host localhost

 INFO  Starting development server...


 DONE  Compiled successfully in 103891ms                                                                            3:30:58 AM

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
  - Network: http://localhost:8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

And here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --host localhost",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

I tried the solutions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54816713/why-is-npm-run-serve-building-slow-on-vue-js) but nothing worked.

Anyone have any ideas?

### Update

Got it to work much faster by switching from working in the windows file system to the Linux one.

Comment: Is the code in a NFS mount, in any chance? Also - which OS are you using?

Comment: @madflow No and I am on WSL2 Ubuntu